# How to identify a procedure is executing recursively in Oracle

Tags: oracle, recursion, plsql, oracle11g, stack-trace

**Oracle Code:**

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY P AS

  /* TODO enter package declarations (types, exceptions, methods etc) here */ 

procedure p3 as
begin
 p1();
end;

procedure p2 as
begin
 dbms_output.put_line('inside p2');
 dbms_output.put_line('p2 call stack - '||dbms_utility.format_call_stack);
 p3();
end;

procedure p1 as
begin

 dbms_output.put_line('inside p1');
 dbms_output.put_line('p1 call stack - '||dbms_utility.format_call_stack);
 p2();
end;

END P;
```

Procedure Calling hierarchy  `P1 -> P2 -> P3 -> P1`

Now, this will be stuck in an recursive call.

I need to identify such recursive call in a procedure and end the calling.

Example in `Oracle 12c` I used, below code (not sure if this is the best way to achieve the same. Please suggest)

```
procedure p1 as
l_depth PLS_INTEGER;
begin

l_depth := UTL_CALL_STACK.dynamic_depth;
dbms_output.put_line('l_depth='||l_depth);
if l_depth > 2 then
 FOR i IN 1 .. l_depth LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line('UTL_CALL_STACK.subprogram(i)='||UTL_CALL_STACK.concatenate_subprogram(UTL_CALL_STACK.subprogram(i)));
      IF upper( UTL_CALL_STACK.concatenate_subprogram(UTL_CALL_STACK.subprogram(i))) like '%P1%' THEN
       dbms_output.put_line('recursive call detected exiting...');
       return;
      END IF; --  IF upper(UTL_CALL_STACK.subprogram(i)) like '%P1%' THEN
 END LOOP;
end if; -- if l_depth > 0 then


 dbms_output.put_line('inside p1');
 dbms_output.put_line('p1 call stack - '||dbms_utility.format_call_stack);
 p2();
end;
```

but I think `subprogram` module in `format_call_stack` is not available in Oracle 11g. Please suggest, how can I achieve the same in Oracle 11g. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to solve the problem on the production environment and adding new param in every proc is not a practical solution in my scenario

You have a coding bug and I believe you are going to have to change *some* code.  There is no `ALTER PACKAGE` command or anything like that to tell Oracle to make it fail if any of the procedures are called reentrantly.

If you don't like adding parameters to each procedure, you can keep track of the number of times each has been called some other way.  An easy way to do this would be have a package-level `NUMBER` variable for each procedure.  Increment the appropriate variable on entry of each procedure and reset it on exit (make sure reset it for exceptions too!).  If, after incrementing, the value is greater than one, it has been called reentrantly and you can act accordingly (based on your requirements).

Sample code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY so_pkg AS

-- Variables to hold lock handles for each procedure
  p1_ctr NUMBER := 0;
  p2_ctr NUMBER := 0;
  p3_ctr NUMBER := 0;

procedure p3 as
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('In P3!');
  p3_ctr := p3_ctr + 1;
  if p3_ctr > 1 THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001,'Reentrancy detected in P3!');
  end if;
  p1;
  p3_ctr := 0;
exception
  when others then
    p3_ctr := 0;
    raise;
end;

procedure p2 as
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('In P2!');
  p2_ctr := p2_ctr + 1;
  if p2_ctr > 1 THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001,'Reentrancy detected in P2!');
  end if;
  p3;
  p2_ctr := 0;
exception
  when others then
    p2_ctr := 0;
    raise;
end;

procedure p1 as
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('In P1!');
  p1_ctr := p1_ctr + 1;
  if p1_ctr > 1 THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001,'Reentrancy detected in P1!');
  end if;
  p2;
  p1_ctr := 0;
exception
  when others then
    p1_ctr := 0;
    raise;
end;

END so_pkg;
```

Results:

> ```
> In P1!
> In P2!
> In P3!
> In P1!
>
> ORA-20001: Reentrancy detected in P1!
> ORA-06512: at "APPS.SO_PKG", line 50
> ORA-06512: at line 1
> ```

You can factor out the counter incrementing, checking, and resetting into separate procedures to reduce the repetitiveness.

Comment: Surely +1 for your solution, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe not the best, but you can simply count your procedure calls:

```
procedure p3(pCount pls_integer) as
begin
 p1(pCount => pCount);
end;

procedure p2(pCount pls_integer) as
begin

 p3(pCount => pCount);
end;

procedure p1(pCount pls_integer default 0) as
lCount pls_integer := pCount;
begin

 lCount := lCount + 1;
 if lCount > 1 then
     return;
 else
  p2(pCount => lCount);
 end if;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, however, I am trying to solve the problem on the production environment and adding new param in every proc is not a practical solution in my scenario. I am trying to find a solution as similar to 12c.